# Jquery for finding number of options

Tags: jquery, html

Here is an example of a drop down menu in my page,

```
<select id="drpdwn">
<option selected="selected">Please select</option> --> This is a static text in my page
<option>serverside value1</option>
<option>serverside value2</option>
<option>serverside value3</option>
</select>
```

Now i need to do some jquery validations for the above drop down menu such as "if the number of options == 1(apart from "please select"), i need to display only that signle option by default. Else, i need to display "please select" as default.

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($("#drpdwn option").length == 2){
         $("#drpdwn option:eq(1)").attr('selected','selected'); 
   }else{
         $("#drpdwn option:eq(0)").attr('selected','selected'); 
   }
});
```

Comment: My page has a static text called "please select" which does not comes from server. Additionally, my drop down menu can hold number of options dynamically. So, your code is not helpful.

Comment: I need a jquery validations such as "i have got be select a default value if only one option comes from the server, else more than one value i need to set "please select as default selected". Please note that "Please select" is a hard coded one and not a dynamic value. My validations are only for dynamic options.